# What role-playing game is best for playing isolated sci-fi single-session adventures?

Tags: game-recommendation, science-fiction

I am interested in running sporadic sci-fi short adventures, preferably with a duration of one session. It should be a fast system and with a simple context.

What system do you recommend?

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPG.SE!  [Your question is likely to be closed and may be better suited for a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) as [shopping and game recommendation questions are off topic here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited).